# match two subsequent pdo fetched rows

Tags: php, pdo

In a classic while statement with PDO, I'd like to compare 2 subsequent database rows.  For example, something like this:

```
<?php while ($r2 = $stm->fetch()): 
   if ($r2['ruolo'][first bd table row]==$r2['ruolo'][second db table row]) {
        do some stuff...
}
?>
```

I want to compare 2 database rows directly; is this possible, and how?

Comment: Do the two rows roll forward such that you start by comparing rows 1,2, then 2,3, then 3,4....?  Must it be done in a `while` fetch loop, or would you accept a solution which used `fetchAll()` to retrieve all rows at once? That would be a little easier to work with, as it would not require temporarily storing the previously fetched row. You could work instead with array indexes on the 2D array.

Comment: Do the two rows roll forward such that you start by comparing rows 1,2, then 2,3, then 3,4....? YES                                                                                                                  Must it be done in a while fetch loop, or would you accept a solution which used fetchAll() to retrieve all rows at once?  I THINK I CAN RETRIEVE ALL ROWS AT ONCE EVEN I WILL ABLE TO COMPARE ROW1-2 2-3...AND SO ON

Comment: I try with fetchall and i solved my issue...but would beter in a while statement...can you suggest me how to do with while?